# Xcode 7: gamecenter 'player' is only available on iOS 8.0 or newer

Tags: xcode, swift, game-center

I'm trying to compile my iOS code in the xcode 7 release candidate, and have run into a strange problem.  I was able to fix all the errors except for this one involving gamecenter.

I've retrieved scores from gamecenter, and am trying to parse through them, getting the scores and the player's name, so I can build a custom leaderboard.  (this was all working in xCode 6, btw).

With xCode 7, I'm getting this error:  "player" is only available on iOS 8.0 or newer.

The code is simple and just looks like this:

```
        myScore = theseScores[i] as! GKScore
        thisName.text = myScores.player.alias
```

Now, I KNOW this code works on iOS 7.  It's out on the appstore now, and I've tested it repeatedly on iOS 7, and it works fine.  So I'm not sure why all of a sudden it is saying that "player" is not available in iOS 7.

I looked up the docs for GKScore, and sure enough, it says that "player" was new in iOS 8. So regardless of how it worked before, it looks like I'm going to have to change it now.  Do I need to do some kind of runtime check to see if we're running on iOS 7, and get the player's name differently?

Or maybe I can just change my app to require iOS 8 or greater? I can't imagine that many people are still on iOS 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed odd if the above code works in iOS7 unless you've changed it on some level. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKScore_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKScore/player) the GKScore's player-property is strictly iOS8 and later...

Are you in fact sure your app does not crash at the `thisName.text = myScores.player.alias` line on iOS7-devices? Xcode 6 does *not* generally warn you if you call functionality unavailable for your deployment-target...

As for targeting iOS8 or greater Apple just updated the information on the App Store support page stating that [87% uses iOS8](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/)...

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why it worked before, but I guess it's irellavent.  To fix it I ended up doing this:

    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
    thisName.text = myScore.player.alias
    } else {
    thisName.text = myScore.playerID
     }